# Three js. Получить сторону куба

Tags: three.js

Задача - имитировать бросок игрального кубика.
На каждую сторону отдельная текстура - значение кости.
Как определить, какая сторона куба сверху?

**Обновление**

Проблема заключается в том, что в качестве объекта у меня куб. И не получается определить положение сторон куба.

Например:
Условно обозначим стороны куба 1-6.
Куб с позицией:

`cube.position.x=0; .position.y=0; .position.z=0;`

Задаю вращение куба:

```
cube.rotation.x += 0.02;
```

В результате сверху у меня сначала одна сторона куба, потом другая и т.д. Позиция самого объекта остается такой же 0/0/0. Задача - определить, какая сторона куба "сверху".

Как я вижу решение этой задачи - получить в качестве объекта стороны куба и сравнивать position.y.

Как получить сторону куба? Или другие варианты...

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что в качестве обьекта у меня куб. И не получается определить положение сторон куба.
Например: 
Условно обозначим стороны куба 1-6.
Куб с позицией - cube.position.x=0; .position.y=0; .position.z=0;
В задаю вращение куба.
cube.rotation.x += 0.02;
В результате сверху у меня сначала одна сторона куба, потом другая и т.д. Позиция самого обьекта остается такой же 0/0/0. Задача - определить какая сторона куба "сверху".
Как я вижу решение этой задачи - получить в качестве обьекта стороны куба и сравнивать position.y. 
Как получить сторону куба? или другие варианты...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Подключить [библиотеку](http://chandlerprall.github.io/Physijs/).
2. Определить можно либо по повороту игральной кости относительно мировых координат

Готовый пример: http://jsfiddle.net/4x3wgvvb/

Разумеется, рассчеты можно вынести в отдельную функцию, и вызывать ее единожды после выполнения анимации физическим движком.

По мировой матрице меша определяются направления векторов для трех осей по каждой паре граней.

Comment: библиотеку уже использую - спасибо.
Вершины фейсов - console.log(cube.geometry.faces);
спасибо. буду читать - пробовать.

Comment: Пробую определять по face'ам, но пока результата нет. 
Массив face'ов одинаков в разных положениях куба.
Есть вариант определять по атрибуту rotation но пока с алгоритмом определения стороны справиться не получается.

Comment: Построил куб "вручную".
Задал каждой стороне свой цвет. Лучем получаю обьект и смотрю цвет.
Вот что получилось: http://threejs.wisp.su/cubesideselect/

Comment: для такого использовать райкаст вообще не оптимально, лучше вычислять по повороту.
Обновил ответ